# Most concise way to get a value from within a tibble

Tags: r, unit-testing, tidyverse

I'm setting up tests.  I operate on test-data, then want to assure that the right value showed up in a cell in a tibble.  I think there's a more concise way to this. Using the example `band_instruments`

```
library(tidyverse)
test_that("Musicians play instruments", {
      expect_equal(band_instruments %>% filter(name == "Paul") %>% pull("plays"),
                   "bass")
      expect_equal({band_instruments %>% filter(name == "Keith")}$plays,
                   "guitar")
})
```

This works, but it's too long, too wordy.  What's the most concise, yet readable way to do such tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks quite neat to me:

```
test_that("Musicians play instruments", {
  expect_equal(with(band_instruments, plays[name == "Paul"]), "bass")
  expect_equal(with(band_instruments, plays[name == "Keith"]), "guitar")})
```

Or perhaps this:

```
with(band_instruments, test_that("Musicians play instruments", {
  expect_equal(plays[name == "Paul"], "bass")
  expect_equal(plays[name == "Keith"], "guitar")}))
```

Comment: Thanks @allan-cameron.  I really like the second one.
I started R with _R for Data Science_.  I think I need to now go back and learn the pre-tidyverse idioms.

Comment: No problem @DavidT. I've found that answering questions on Stack Overflow is a great way to learn these old tricks. I've been writing in R for almost a decade now, but only learned about `with` in SO a couple of months ago.