# Why I'm getting NA's when selecting by 'with'

Tags: r

As a followup to @allan-cameron 's excellent answer in [Most concise way to get a value from within a tibble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702740/most-concise-way-to-get-a-value-from-within-a-tibble)

If I add some `NA` to `band-instruments`

```
bandy <- tibble(name = c("John", "Paul", "Keith", "Eric", NA), 
               plays = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", NA, "kazoo")) 

with(bandy, plays[name == "John"])
# [1] "guitar" NA  

with(bandy, name[plays == "guitar"])
# [1] "John"  "Keith" NA
```

Can someone explain *why* I'm getting those NA's returned?  And what's the most elegant way to keep from returning them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that those NA are unrelated to `with` function or `tibble` format. See for example:

```r
x <- c(1, 2, NA)
x[x == 1]
#> [1]  1 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For the help page of the `==` function we can read:

> Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA.

and from the help page of the `[` function we can read:

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a list. (It returns 00 for a raw result.)

So this is the reason why that code returns `NA`.

IMO the easiest way to avoid those NA is the following:

```r
library(tibble)
bandy <- tibble(name = c("John", "Paul", "Keith", "Eric", NA), 
                plays = c("guitar", "bass", "guitar", NA, "kazoo")) 

with(bandy, plays[name == "John" & !is.na(name)])
#> [1] "guitar"
with(bandy, name[plays == "guitar" & !is.na(plays)])
#> [1] "John"  "Keith"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `%in%` which returns `FALSE` where there are `NA`

```
with(bandy, plays[name %in% 'John'])
#[1] "guitar"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out the reason. However, here is the solution .

```
> with(bandy, plays[(name == "John") & !is.na(name)])
[1] "guitar"

> with(bandy, name[(plays == "guitar") & !is.na(plays)])
[1] "John"  "Keith"
```

Another option is using dplyr

```
> filter(bandy, name == "John")$plays
[1] "guitar"

> filter(bandy, plays == "guitar")$name 
[1] "John"  "Keith"
```